# Weird keywords in google webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

I just happened to check the keywords list on Google Webmaster Tools for my site, which is an educational content site about finance. To my big surprise, after the first keyword, which is 'finance', I found amongst the 20 highest ranked (!) entries words like: mysql, server, adobe, flash, player, homez.

What (i'm tempted to add "the heck") does that mean ? Is that something I should worry about? If so, how did these get there and how can I eliminate these / avoid they get into that list ?

Thanks very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a search for `site:yoursite.com homez` and you will find many mysql-errors.

For a while your site has had a problem with the SQL-database. Google has indexed all the error-messages on 13 Jun 2011 06:03:45 GMT

Answer (score 0):

These words may occur in links to your site. If you search Google for `link:yoursite.com` you can look at the links to your site and see what words they are using.

Another reason might be that your site has been hacked and some other pages inserted that you don't know about. It might be one dynamic page (e.g. php) that keeps generating lots of keywords.

Comment: Shouldn't you enter `link:yoursite.com` with NO space aftre the colon? Anyway this type of test most of times gives back nothing! I think Google does not like the idea of SEOs to easy discover inlinks to competitors sites.

Comment: You're right, I've removed the space. Yes, I find that sometimes they don't list links that I'm pretty sure are in the index. I've also expanded my answer.

Comment: @Marco Demaio: The `link:` operator only shows you a very small, random selection of your backlinks, for exactly the reason you bring up. You can get a much larger number of them from within Webmaster Tools, which you're already using.

Comment: @Su': well I know it, it's exactly what I said, it's paulmorriss that is suggesting to use it.